# create legend manually in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have the following code to plot a bar graph - there are 6 species but the code groups them into three coloured groupings.

I then want to make a legend of the three groups with three colours. However, the legend only features the first grouping (which is colored correctly!) and then ignores the other groupings (see image)

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create data frame
G = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(100,20,size=(30, 1)), columns=list('G'))
T = []
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(5):
        T.append('Species'+repr(i))
T = pd.DataFrame(np.array(T).reshape(30,1), columns = list("T"))
cols = ['g','b','k']
C=[]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(10):
        C.append(cols[i])
C = pd.DataFrame(np.array(C).reshape(30,1), columns = list("C"))
dat = pd.concat([G, C, T], axis = 1)
dat.columns = ['growth', 'cols', 'sp']

#begin code to make plot
grps = sorted(list(set(list(dat['sp']))))
meanGrs=[]
sems=[]
cols=[]
y_pos = np.arange(len(grps))
for grp in grps:
    qw = 'sp == "' + grp + '"'
    meanGrs.append(dat.query(qw)['growth'].mean())
    sems.append(dat.query(qw)['growth'].sem())
    cols.append(str(dat.query(qw)['cols'].max()))

plt.bar(y_pos, meanGrs, yerr=sems, align = 'center', alpha = 0.5, color = cols, label = cols)
plt.legend(('group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'))
plt.xticks(y_pos, grps, ha = 'right', rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you edit with dat.head() for example?

Comment: You mean you want to see a sample of the data?

Comment: yes i want to see a sample please

Comment: This can easily be done by creating the respective legend handles within the loop and suppliying it to the legend call. I would give an answer if there was a [mcve] available.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest done, hope that's OK

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html?highlight=proxy%20artist#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists

Comment: @PaulH  - all the examples on this involve calling the plot separately, I don't see how it helps (I only call the plot once)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what would determine which group is which in this case. But if that is arbitrary you can just create the groups on the fly.

```
legenditems = [(plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=c, alpha=0.5), "group "+str(i+1))
                 for i,c in enumerate(np.unique(cols))]
plt.legend(*zip(*legenditems))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

l1 = mpatches.Patch(color='k', label='group 1')
l2 = mpatches.Patch(color='b', label='group 2')
l3 = mpatches.Patch(color='g', label='group 3')
plt.legend(handles=[l1, l2, l3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
for _ in dat['sp']: #looping here keeps the order
if _ not in grps:
    grps.append(_)

i=0
for grp in grps:
    dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'meanGrs']= dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'growth'].mean()
    dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'sems']= dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'growth'].sem()
    plt.bar(i, dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'meanGrs'], 
              yerr=dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'sems'], align = 'center', 
              alpha = 0.5, color = dat.loc[dat['sp']==grp,'cols'])
    i=i+1
    plt.legend(('group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4'))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the argument "label" in the plt.bar:

```
plt.bar(y_pos, meanGrs, yerr=sems, align = 'center', alpha = 0.5, color = cols, label=cols)
```

Comment: I get the same result