# Add a legend to a mosaic plot from python's statsmodels

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

This is a mosaic plot in python, using `statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

props = {}
for x in ['small', 'large']:
    for y, col in {'short': 'purple', 'medium': 'blue', 'long': 'yellow'}.items():
        props[(x, y)] ={'color': col}

df = pd.DataFrame({'size' : ['small', 'large', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'large'], 'length' : ['long', 'short', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'short', 'long', 'medium']})

mosaic(df, ['size', 'length'], properties=props, labelizer=lambda k: '')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I add a color legend on the side for the `length` variable, using the dictionary in the `props` definition? (I realize it's not a necessity in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to do it by creating custom legends as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854609/4932316) answer by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest). Please note that I introduced a dictionary `col_dic` for sake of ease.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

props = {}
# Dictionary introduced here
col_dic = {'short': 'purple', 'medium': 'blue', 'long': 'yellow'}
for x in ['small', 'large']:
    for y, col in col_dic.items():
        props[(x, y)] ={'color': col}

df = pd.DataFrame({'size' : ['small', 'large', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'large'], 'length' : ['long', 'short', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'short', 'long', 'medium']})

mosaic(df, ['size', 'length'], properties=props, labelizer=lambda k: '')

# Part added by me based on the linked answer
legenditems = [(plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=col_dic[c]), "%s" %c)
                 for i,c in enumerate(df['length'].unique().tolist())]
plt.legend(*zip(*legenditems))

plt.show()
```

[image]